# Consider nonzero $A_{2\times 2}$ such that $A^2 = \vec{0}$. Prove or disprove that dim$($ker$(A)) = 2$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having a couple of difficulties with this problem. The first comes with finding an $A$ such that $A^2 = \vec{0}$. In the case of a $2 \times 2 $ matrix, it seems simple enough to try a few combinations until one works, but what if $A$ had been say, $5 \times 5$? Is there any simple method to determine $A$ given some $A^x = \vec{y}$ for scalars $x$ and vector $y$, or is this just a particular case?

My second confusion is with what dim$($ker$(A))$ precisely means. To my understanding dim$(\mathbb{R^n})$ is equal to the number of vectors in a basis for $\mathbb{R^n}$. So how do we make sense of the number of vectors in a basis for ker$(A)$? If ker$(A) = \vec{0}$, is dim$($ker$(A)) = 0$, since $\vec{0}$ is not linearly independent?

Comment: If $A$ is a (square) matrix, and $x$ is an integer, then $A^x$ is a matrix, not a vector. Finding a $5\times5$ matrix such that $A^2=0$ is finding one whose column space is contained in its nullspace. You can make the column space 2-dimensional by picking any pair of linearly independent vectors to be the first two columns and then making all the other columns linear combinations of the first two. You have to choose the linear combinations carefully to make the columns lie in the nullspace. Try it!

Comment: Had a chance to think about these things?

Answer (score 1):

You are right that if $ker(A)=\vec 0$ then $dim(ker(A))=0$

Here it is rather the opposite: $dim(ker(A))=2$ means that $ker(A)=\mathbb R^2$, so for all $x$, $Ax=0$, meaning $A=0$. The question can be reformulated: "is there a nonzero $2\times 2$ matrice $A$ such that $A^2=0$ ?"

Hint: the answer is yes, try to find such a matrice.

Comment: What if the $A$ were $5 \times 5$ instead? Are there any methods that give $A^2 = 0$ directly?

Comment: for any size $n\times n$, if you take a matrix with only a $1$ at the upper right, and $0$ elsewhere, it will be that $A^2=0$, and $dim(ker(A))=n-1$.